# mongoose saves an empty object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a promblem with saving data to db, mongoose saves empty object without value. Using mean stack.

controller:
for example i send some "hello message"

```
    $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/message',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            data: JSON.stringify({msg: $scope.message})      
        }).

        success(function(response) {
            console.log("Success " + JSON.stringify(response));
        }).

        error(function(response) {
            console.log("Error " + JSON.stringify(response));
        });
```

server.js

```
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/vnd.api+json'}));

    var message = mongoose.model('Message', {
    message: String
    })

    app.post('/api/message', function(req,res) {
    var message = new Message(req.body);
    message.save(function(err) {
        if(err) throw err;

        console.log(message);
    })

    res.status(200).send();
    console.log(req.body);
    })
```

my "hello" message reaches the server, but mongoose saves an empty object

```
{msg: "hello"} // console.log(req.body);
{"_id":"584ee18f169f902b7046e991","__v":0} // console.log(message);
```

what im doing wrong??

Comment: Add your definition / declaration of `Message`, please.

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: `req.body` will not be properly populated without a body parser. have you added the express-js [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)?

Comment: yes, i did, upadet topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mismatch between your request body and the `Message` definition. `req.body` contains a `msg` property, but `Message` is expecting a `message` property.

I would swap the following line in your angular controller:

```
data: JSON.stringify({msg: $scope.message})
```

To this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({message: $scope.message})
```

You could also update the `Message` model to have a property named `msg` instead of changing your angular code, if you'd prefer.

Comment: I stumbled upon a similar issue and found out that mongoose discards any key-value pairs that aren't defined in the schema.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as you are sending `data` key object in body

```
 app.post('/api/message', function(req,res) {
    var message = new Message(req.body.data);
    message.save(function(err) {
        if(err) throw err;

        console.log(message);
    })

    res.status(200).send();
    console.log(req.body);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use spread function in es6 to assign req.body to new Message object. You should try modifying your server.js like below

```
app.post('/api/message', function(req,res) {
var message = new Message({ ...req.body });
message.save()
.then(msg => res.status(200).send())
.catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

Comment: model.save() in mongoose returns a promise, you should use .then() function to send the response, see my edited answer. Let me know if this fixes your issue

Comment: Object spread is only in [stage 3](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread), and isn't ES6.

Comment: server returns syntax error for the spread function,
synatx error unexpected token ...